Permissions On a Event Webpart And Announcements Web Part
I have been tasked with setting permissions for a SharePoint user to be able to edit the Event web part only and then another user edits the announcement web part Only. Can you set permissions on the web part itself?
I have looked in to setting the permissions on the site itself, but it is for the whole site not just that web part.

Currently we are unable to assign permissions to Web Parts in SharePoint Online.
Permissions can only be set in SharePoint for sites, document libraries/lists, or file/list items.

Ok , thanks. I Hope that functionality comes available in the future.
